# Combining regexps in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a code like that

```
(str =~ /regexp1/) && (str !~ /regexp2/) ? "aa" : "bb"
```

Is there a way to combine two regexp in one check to have a shorter code?

Answer (score 3):

vks's regex somewhat makes a point, but is not completely correct. Do this:

```
/\A(?!.*#{regexp2}).*#{regexp1}/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a bit shorter with:

```
str[/regexp1/] && !str[/regexp2/] ? "aa" : "bb"
```

The other solutions I'm seeing here are an unnecessary nightmare for the guy who needs to read your code. Avoid them.

Comment: pg, this really doesn't address the question. The question is not whether a mind-bending regex should be used if that's what it takes to combine the two regexes. I doubt that anyone reading this would answer that question in the affirmative. There may be something useful to be learned, however, by studying the solutions that are offered, possible nuggets that might have application in other situations.

Comment: @Cary I don't agree, I think you're encouraging bad code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using negative lookahead.

```
(?!.*regexp2)regexp1
```

`.*` is needed to make sure `regexp2` is not present anywhere in the string. For ex.

`regexp2="bb"` and `regexp1 ="cc"`. Here, `.*` is not needed as it is straightforward. But if

`regexp2="bb"` and `regexp1="ccbbaa"` Here, `.*` is needed to make sure `bb` is not present anywhere in the string.

Comment: Can you please explain why do we need ".*" in it?

Comment: it won't work for several cases. @VictorRonin could you provide an example?

Comment: Wait, your regex prohibits `regexp2` at or after the point where `regexp1` matches, but does it prohibit `regexp2` that appears before that?

Comment: @sawa can be easily done with anchors.But i m not sure if OP wants that

Comment: @sawa for OP (?!regexp2)regexp1 is enuf

Comment: @vks - Not really: `"regexp2regexp1"[/(?!regexp2)regexp1/] => "regexp1"`